# SwiftUI display Data from Apollo query into list

Tags: swift, swiftui, apollo, swiftui-list

```
var projects = [FetchProjectsQuery.Data.MyProject?]()

func fetchProjects()
{
    let fetcProjectsQuery = FetchProjectsQuery(ownerId: self.ownerId!)
    apolloClient.fetch(query: fetcProjectsQuery)
    {
        result in

        switch result
        {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)

        case .success(let success):
            print(success)

            if let projects = success.data?.myProjects
            {
                print("PRJECTS \(projects)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I display the fetched data into list? Can someone help me?
I am new to swiftui and i want to learn more about fetching data and display data

Comment: This syntax is giving me Java flashbacks.

Comment: Can you show me the struct where you want to show the list in? Because this is quite simple right by just calling ```List(fetchProjects()) { project in }``` etc